# Can ARRAY_CONTAINS accept multiple values in Cosmos

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Do you have sample if i want to match multiple values of one attribute in Array_contains

select * from c where c.sid="1" and c.unum=39 and ARRAY_CONTAINS (c.dcodes,"DIST,DEFT")
where dcodes is my array having just list of codes in my document. so i want to pull all the records for the dcodes i passed into the query it may be one or many.

Comment: @UmeshSherma  could you for cliarity provide one simple document in JSON? Just to see its structure?  You say that dcodes is an array? not a simple field?

Answer (score 1):

You're currently just passing a single string. You need to pass an array of values as your first parameter to `ARRAY_CONTAINS()`. So in your case, if you wanted to select all documents whose property `c.dcodes` contains either `"DIST"` or `"DEFT"`, you'd need to do something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM c
WHERE c.sid="1" and c.unum=39
AND ARRAY_CONTAINS (["DIST","DEFT"],c.dcodes)
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me. Also in the docs for ARRAY_CONTAINS there are no info that second argument can be an array.

Comment: The array would be on the left. The property `c.dcodes` in my example would be a single string containing either "DIST", "DEFT", or something completely different, which would result in not matching. Note that the OP didn't provide a clear example of their schema but... the array would be on the left side. And can be either array of scalar values or an array of objects (which requires a 3rd parameter to clarify that). *I suggest you post a new question though, because I really can't help with your comment - I don't know what doesn't work.*

Comment: I guess it should be clear enough that this function ARRAY_CONTAINS accepts at least one array argument. I believe OP asked about being able to pass an array to the second argument, so the query would return an item where `c.dcodes` contains all or any of the items from the second array argument.