# Cosmos DB - Efficient query to find list of items in an array?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Consider the following documents:

```
{
    "id": "0001",
    "name": "product 1",
    "description": "product 1 description",
    "categories": ["category1", "category2"]
}

{
    "id": "0002",
    "name": "product 2",
    "description": "product 2 description",
    "categories": ["category2", "category3"]
}

{
    "id": "0003",
    "name": "product 3",
    "description": "product 1 description",
    "categories": ["category1", "category4"]
}
```

What I want to do is find the products where the product category could be `category2` or `category3`.

To fetch this, I wrote the following query:

```
Select * from Root r where 
exists(select value c from c in r.categories where c in ("category2", "category3"))
```

The query above works well and gives me the desired results.

What I am wondering is if this query can be improved?

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking with `array_contains()`? I have an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61194997/272109) that has an example of doing something similar.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Thanks! Unfortunately that query does not give me any results. This is the query I wrote: `Select * from Root r where ARRAY_CONTAINS(["category2", "category3"], r.categories)`. Please note that I am not searching for a single value in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_contains` looks for a single item in an array, the item you are looking for is the second argument. So you need:

```
select *
from c
where array_contains(c.categories, "category2")
  or array_contains(c.categories, "category3")
```

And then look at the performance.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate your answer. Let me try it out later.

Comment: Richard - So I tried using `array_contains` and in my tests it is certainly cheaper than using `exists`. I will add another answer with my findings for the sake of completeness. Thanks for all your help.