# How to pass a list in an @Query for an SQL that uses IN?

Tags: java, azure-cosmosdb

In Java, using the Azure Cosmos Query annotation, I am trying to pull data where the ID matches one of the IDs provided:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.id IN (@ids)")
List<Object> getItems(@Param("ids") String ids);
```

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.id IN ("111", "222", "333")
```

I cannot pass the IDs as a List, or directly convert the List into a String, because it will include the square brackets[] as part of the search criteria, and it will also be treated as one item, as opposed to an array of items.

In reference to the following solution [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/20074), I tried converting the List into a String, and then manipulate the String so that it includes quotes around each item within a comma delimited fashion. However it returns no data, even when there's just one item in the List. This is the case for both single and double quotes.

This is my current solution from List to String:

```
String ids= list.stream().map(s -> "'" + s + "'").collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

In Java, how do I pass a list in an @Query for an SQL that uses IN?

Comment: `List<Object> getItems(@Param("ids") List<*class of the ids*> ids);`

Comment: @Jens I've tried that, it doesn't work, returns no results

Comment: No result does not meas it doesn't work. Are you sure you should get a result. Have you looked into logfiles how the generated query looks like?

Comment: I've been trying to amend my application.yml to show this in the logs. I've not found the right settings yet.

Comment: ```com.azure.cosmos.implementation.SqlQuerySpecLogger: debug``` this works somewhat, but it showing the variable names and not their values

Comment: I think I've got it, I can use ```Array_Contains``` instead of ```IN```

Comment: @Kurtiss - great that you are using `array_contains()` - I was going to suggest it, if you had not already mentioned it. FYI I've posted a few answers related to `array_contains()`, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61194997/272109) - that particular one illustrates a scalar array - you can also use it with arrays of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Change `IN` to `Array_Contains`

`SELECT * FROM c WHERE Array_Contains(@ids, ids))`